# Undefined when trying to do a post nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

yesterday this worked perfectly fine but now for some reason it's giving me Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined.

My route for posting the task/todo is

```js
app.post('/task/create', (req, res) => {
    // get the date object to format our date and our task from the form.
    let date = new Date();
    let task = req.body.task;
    let currentDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`;

    // Form our query and then execute it.
    let query = ('INSERT INTO tasks(task, created_at, completed) value (?, ?, ?)', [task, currentDate, false]);
    pool.getConnection()
    .then(conn => {
      conn.query(query)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
          conn.end()
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle error
          console.log(err); 
          conn.end();
        })
        
    }).catch(err => {
      //not connected
      console.log("not connected");
    });

    res.redirect('/');
});
```

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks(task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, task VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, created_at DATE NOT NULL, completed BOOL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(task_id)`
I'm using a mariadb database which has a table which is setup like this

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I can suggest you to check your DB config settings and re-run DB migrations

Comment: how do i migrate it?

Comment: Which administration tool do you using? Try to find your setup queries and re-run them.